# Sending Authorization Header in Ionic 3 and Angular 5 through HTTPClient

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I am calling REST API from ionic 3 and Http Client, I am using Http Interceptor, When I am setting header name in the code, it is going under "Access-Control-Request-Headers:" see the attached [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFNx4.png)

and my code is :

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpsRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
    Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const dupReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*').append('ABC','xxx') });
        return next.handle(dupReq);
    }
};
@NgModule({
   providers: [
       { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpsRequestInterceptor, multi: true }
   ]
})
export class InterceptorModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have handled cors on the frontend, But it also needs to be handled from the backend, Moreover, install this extension and turn it on before making the http call and you will be able to receive response
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, Agha Ali Abbas, I  tried the above option but did not solve my issue.